# Can we measure only vertical mouse speed using cursormeter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have been searching for a week now with no success for a way I can get only the vertical mouse speed using Jquery

Cursormeter is great but not confined only to vertical speed: http://www.loganfranken.com/blog/49/capturing-cursor-speed/

Can someone please advice?

Comment: Write your own? It's super-simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursormeter is on github (https://github.com/loganfranken/Cursometer) so you could fork it and modify it to fit your needs. It is calculating distance on line 178

```
distance = Math.sqrt(xDiff + yDiff);
```

You could modify that to only use one axis. For example if you wanted up/down speed, change it to

```
distance = Math.sqrt(yDiff);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `jQuery` Plugin called `scroll-speed`which allows you to get the scroll speed of the `Window`or another `div`

You can download it here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-speed

So once you download it you would do something like this:

```
speed.on('scroll', callback(event))
```